# How to position an element to the bottom right of a div

Tags: html, css

The container div has a fixed width of 540px min-height of 200px.
i want to put another div on the bottom right corner of that div...
how should i do that

```
<div style="width:540px; min-height:200px;" class="container">
  <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;" class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely not `absolute` since it should be "relative" to the containing `div` right?

Comment: your outer `div` should be positioned as `relative` to make the inner absolute work expectedly. Just add `position:relative` to the style of the outer div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:540px; min-height:200px; position:relative;" class="container">
  <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;" class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

you should add a position:relative; in the .container

Comment: thanks hanze :) it worked. is there are any way without making it absolute? like it'll be stick to the bottom right but will work like a normal (static) element?

Answer (score 1):

The following works (for demo purposes):

```
<div style="width:540px; min-height:200px; position:relative; border: 1px solid red;" class="container">
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; border: 1px solid blue;" class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4Aj9/)

You can always separate the CSS into "container" and "block" classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:540px; min-height:200px; position:relative; border: 1px solid red;" class="container">
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; position:absolute; bottom:0; border: 1px solid blue; margin-left : 480px;" class="block">
 </div>
 </div>
```

This would also help you. Specify the size of block div and subtract its size from container div and keep the result in margin-left.